# Setting the class of HTML elements using Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a Rails app with Twitter Bootstrap installed. Bootstrap encapsulates each navigation bar link in a HTML list element, like so:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

When a link is the current page, Bootstrap allows you to highlight it by setting the list element's class (not the link itself) to "active", like so:

```
    <li class="active"><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
```

My question is: **how do you set the list element's class to "active" (if it is the current page) programmatically using Rails?**

I know how it can be done for a link. Example:

```
<%= link_to "Products", products_path, :class => "active" if current_page?(:controller => "products") %>
```

But I don't know how it can be done for the parent list element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`content_tag` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag):

```
<%= content_tag :li, :class => 'active' do %>
  List item contents
<% end %>
```

Comment: But how to set the class to "active" only if it is the current page? I tried `<%= content_tag :li, :class => 'active' if current_page?(:controller => "products") do %>` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, figured it out. Needs to be:


`<%= content_tag :li, :class => ('active' if current_page?(:controller => "products")) do %>`.

In other words, the class' value needs to be encapsulated in parentheses. @georgebrock can you update your answer to reflect this?