# How to apply css Styling in Ruby on Rails HTML page?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in RoR. I am trying to add css classes on my form. Here is my form:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' do %>
  <p><label for = "name">Name</label>:
    <%= text_field 'books', 'name' %></p>
  <div class="form-control">
  <p><label for = "author">Author</label>:
    <%= text_field 'books', 'author'%></p>
  </div>
  <p><label for = "price">Price</label><br/>
    <%= text_area 'books', 'price'%></p>
  <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end -%>
```

That form controls does not accepting `class="form-control mb-4 col-10" placeholder="Patient name"` like `<input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control mb-4 col-10" placeholder="Patient name">`. How can I apply css styling.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no accepting?' Have you tried defining the css in `app/assets/stylesheets/*somefile*.css` and referencing the file in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` through ` *= require *somefile*.css ` Are you attempting to set the class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting the class of HTML elements using Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572514/setting-the-class-of-html-elements-using-rails)

Comment: I am using online style sheet <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> for stling.

Comment: Also, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507101/how-to-add-styling-to-a-single-input-in-a-form-for It's in HAML but idea is basically the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the class behind a comma

```
<%= text_field 'books' :name, class:"form-control mb-4 col-10", placeholder="Patient name" %>
```